# How do I pull the selected values from a select tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I've created a Django template and I'm trying to get the selected value from an options tag using JavaScript. However, while my current code runs without issue, there is no response when I click submit. The other webpage isn't loaded, regardless of what option I select. Can anyone help with why this is happening?

```
<!doctype html>
<h1>Searching for a particular tag?</h1>

<input type="text" id="target"/>
<select single="single" name="tag_options" id="tag_options">
    <option value="0">Hello</option>
    <option value="1">Goodbye</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" onclick="search()">Submit</button>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'frontpage' %}">Front Page</a>

<script>
    function search(){
        var values =  $('#tag_options').val();
        this.document.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/searchtableresults/"+values;

    }

</script>
```

Additionally, I would eventually like to change the options from static choices to choices based on values I load in from a view, like so

```
<!doctype html>
<h1>Searching for a particular tag?</h1>

<input type="text" id="target"/>
<select single="single" name="tag_options" id="tag_options">
    {% for possible_tag in possible_tags %}
    <option value="{{possible_tag}}">{{possible_tag}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<button type="submit" onclick="search()">Submit</button>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'frontpage' %}">Front Page</a>

<script>
    function search(){
        var values =  $('#tag_options').val();
        this.document.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/searchtableresults/"+values;

    }

</script>
```

Would this work or do I need to try something else?

Comment: Is the `submit` button within a `<form>` element?

Comment: Try to use `form` instead of this  `search()` function with changing href. Try to play with jquery more to understand what is going on. Hit `$("#tag_options")` in console and watch what it will return.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this using *jquery* would work:

```
//Get select element
const tagSelect = document.querySelector('#tag_options');

//Access Options
let selectedTag = tagSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('value');
```

To change options:

```
let tags = []

//Create
tags.forEach(tag => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('blah-blah', tag.whatever);
  tagSelect.appendChild(option);
})
```

Hope this helps in some way...